# Soql query to retrieve data from three related object

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, query, relationships

I have three custom objects: Book, Loan, and Reader. Loan is a junction object with lookup relationship with both Book and Reader. The diagram below shows their relationship:

[image]

I want to write a SOQL query to retrieve the Loan name and Active status from Loan object, Book title and subject from Book object, and Reader name and specialization subject from Reader object.

I wrote the following query but it showing an error:

```
SELECT Active__c, Name, 
       (SELECT Name, Subject__c FROM Book__r), 
       (SELECT Name, Specialization_Subject__c FROM Reader__r) 
FROM Loan__c
```

I get the following error message:

> Didn't understand relationship 'Book__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've written your query in parent-child subquery form, but `Loan__c` is in fact the child object. You need to traverse the relationship upwards to obtain data from the related `Book__c` and `Reader__c` objects:

```
SELECT Active__c, Name, 
       Book__r.Name, Book__r.Subject__c, 
       Reader__r.Name, Reader__r.Specialization_Subject__c 
FROM Loan__c
```

Comment: that works fine. thank you